# How to open a popup window with a spinner in python + Gtk

Tags: python, user-interface, popup, gtk, glade

I have a python Gtk application, with the GUI designed in Glade. It has a "scan" feature which will scan the network for a few seconds and then report its results to the user. During the scanning I want a popup window to appear stealing the focus from the parent until scanning is done.

I use a threading.Lock to synchronize the GUI and the scan thread, which makes the popup to last exactly the right time I want (see scanLock.acquire() ). It seems straightforward to me to implement something like a show() and hide() call before and after the scanLock.acquire(). I did use waitPopupShow and waitPopupHide instead of just calling the window.show() and window.hide() because I also may want to set the Label in the popup or start/stop the GtkSpinner. Here is some code from the GUI class:

```
def scan(self):
    sT = scannerThread(self,self.STagList) 
    self.dataShare.threadsList.append(sT)
    sT.start() # start scanning
    self.waitPopupShow('Scanning... Please Wait')
    self.scanLock.acquire() # blocks here until scan is finished
    self.waitPopupHide()

def waitPopupShow(self, msg): # shows a GtkSpinner until the semaphore is cleared
    self.waitDialogLabel.set_text(msg)
    self.waitDialogBox.show_all()
    self.waitDialog.show()
    self.waitDialogSpinner.start()

def waitPopupHide(self):
    # how to get the handle to the spinner and stop it?
    self.waitDialogSpinner.stop()
    self.waitDialog.hide()

def getAll(self):
    # GUI
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(path to main GUI)
    # ... getting stuff from a first glade file

    # getting stuff from the waitDialog glade file
    self.builder.add_from_file(path to waitDialog GUI)
    self.waitDialog = self.builder.get_object("waitDialog") # GtkWindow
    self.waitDialogBox = self.builder.get_object("waitDialogBox") # GtkBox
    self.waitDialogLabel = self.builder.get_object("waitDialogLabel") # GtkLabel
    self.waitDialogSpinner = self.builder.get_object("waitDialogSpinner") # GtkSpinner
    self.waitDialog.hide()
```

I'm trying hardly since a couple of days to show a dialog with a label and a Gtk.Spinner. The best I obtain at the moment is to have the window showing up with no content. Please note that the self.waitDialog.hide() right after getting it with self.builder.get_object is needed because I set the property of the waitDialog Gtkwindow to Visibile. If I stop with the debugger before .hide() the waitDialog shows up perfectly. Afterwards its broken.

This is the waitDialog GUI file: http://pastebin.com/5enDQg3g

[image: current screenshot]

So my best guess is that I'm dooing something wrong, and I could find nothing on creating a new Gtk window over the main one, only basic examples and dialogs. A pointer to the documentation saying a bit about this would be a good starting point...

Comment: Have a look at the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833194/creating-widgets-that-automatically-update-in-gtk-while-still-being-able-to-cont?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more of a Gtk related problem. There must be something in the use of Gtk.window methods and properties which I'm missing.

Comment: Sure. You need to allow the gtk main loop to run while your scan is running, otherwise gtk can't process events in your popup and update the spinner. The question I linked to discusses how to deal with that situation using `gobject.timeout_add()` and `gobject.idle_add()`.

Comment: Ok, I realize what you mean. I can move all the code in scan (especially the blocking .acquire() line) in another function scanPerform, and in scan() just call the gobject.idle_add(scanPerform). Unfortunately the spinner and label in the popup do not show up.